# Import Eclipse project into IntelliJ while keeping them synced

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, karel

I'm trying to import Eclipse Project to IntelliJ while keeping them synced, because I want to use IntelliJ as an IDE but keep Eclipse project in the way it is now and if it anything, directly upload my programming assignments (as an Eclipse project). In other words, I want to edit Eclipse project with IntelliJ IDE, that's all.

After some searching, I discovered that you can do that in IntelliJ Like that:

Import project -> [Choose .project File] -> Keep project and module files in [some other directory] & Link created IntelliJ IDEA modules to Eclipse project files -> [Select project to import, "Empty Karel Project" in my case]

However, no .java files in my project whatsoever. That's where I need help. Am I missing or misinterpreting something? By the way, Eclipse Integration plugin is enabled.

Project files after importing:
[image: Project files after importing]

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach a sample project to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA allows you to import projects from Eclipse in two ways. If you do not need backwards compatibility, you typically instruct IntelliJ IDEA to create a new set of native project files. Otherwise, you can instruct IntelliJ IDEA to keep project files in sync so that you can work on the project from both environments.

1. Click Import Projectfrom the Quick Start window or select the File → Import Project ...menu item. Next, select the .classpath file or .project file to import and confirm.

And for other ways you can refer below link
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59944389

Comment: I already did these steps but only project files I get in IntelliJ are .eml and .iml files,  whereas I expected .java, .class, .classpath, .project files etc.